# I am having trouble understanding why does the output change after removing a variable from a subclass

Tags: c++

Hello in the code below the output is "A", I don't understand why the output (the 'value' variable) changes to "B" after removing the value variable from the subclass B

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:

    string value;
    A(){
        value = "A";
    }

    void display(){
        cout<<value<<endl;
    }

};

class B : public A{
public:

    string value;
    B(){
        value = "B";
    }


};

int main(){
    A *c = new B();
    c->display();

}
```

Comment: What's the compiler diagnostics if you turn on warnings? (Hm, surprisingly gcc 5.4.0 does not warn about the shadowing.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I was also surprised but I think they may have their reasons to not make it so. This kind of shadowing is crucial to the implementation of `std::tuple`, for example, so G++ would be cutting its own branch. And if they somehow disabled the warning for standard includes, they would prevent programmers from implementing a similar functionality which is perfectly compliant with the standard.

Answer (score 6):

When both classes have a variable named `value` The `B` constructor refers to `B::value`.

After you removed it from `B`, it started referring to `A::value`, and assigning to it.

Make the variables `A::value` private, and you'll see the compiler complain that you try to access an inaccessible member variable.

Answer (score 6):

There's no such thing as overriding variables in C++, you don't need to re-declare `value` in `B` to make it accessible (being `public` or `protected` in `A` does that for you). In fact, at the moment you declare `string value` within B, it creates a **different** member **shadowing** the other unqualified identifier. The assignment in `B::B()` assigns to that and leaves `A::value` untouched. (You could still specifically refer to `A::value` from within `B` if you wanted, though.)

If you remove `value` from `B`, you see the inherited `A::value` **as** `B::value`, they refer to the same object. Assigning `"B"` to that changes what `A::display()` sees.

### What you may have intended

If you want to make it explicit that you are taking the name `value` from `A`, you can use `using`:

```
class B : public A{
public:

    using A::value;
    B(){
        value = "B";
    }

};
```

The primary uses of this construct are

- exposing the member, e.g., if `A` was derived from as `class B : private A` only,
- referring to a member in a dependent scope, e.g., if you were writing a `template<class A> class B : public A`. (Not knowing *a priori* what `A`'s going to be the compiler wouldn't know what the `value` is you're referring to in the constructor, so it needs a hint it's expected to be a member of the template parameter.)

### Why it's good

Allowing a member of the same name in a derived class can be useful. Imagine that you're writing your class `B` and depend on a member called `value` in it having some semantics. You don't care if someone independently decided to add some utility to your base class `A` for which they also needed a `value`. You don't want errors because the other is a `const` or something. But most importantly, you don't want that to suddenly start overwriting whatever you put into that member variable within the logic of `B`.

Another interesting case is when designing something like a `std::tuple` with a non-fixed inheritance graph. But that's a separate discussion.